# How to change №10 result in php array?

Tags: php, html, sql, ajax

I have to create a top 10 leaderboard. I managed to insert data into database after game is lost with `ajax` and get that data after game is lost. But I can't change last (№ 10) position in leaderboard. If result is not in top 10, change that result instead of № 10 and position should be his position in all of results.

This is getting data from database:

```
<?php
require("db_connection.php");
$id = 0;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Leaderboard ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$datas = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
        $datas[] = $row;
        $id = $id + 1;
        echo "<tr><td>" . $id . "</td><td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['score'] . "</td></tr>";
    }
}
?>
```

This is JS:

```
$.post($("#myForm").attr("action"), $("input.info").serializeArray(), function(info) {
    console.log(info);
});
$("#Datas").load('./php/get.php');
```

This is HTML:

```
<div id="Leaderboard">
    <table id="Datas">
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Score</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should load your data back after the first request has ended:

```
 $.post($("#myForm").attr("action"), $("input.info").serializeArray(), function(info) {
    console.log(info);
    $("#Datas").load('./php/get.php');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP array_reverse function to reverse the order of the array (assuming it is already ranked 1-10. 
Try passing the $result into array_reverse and then outputting the result

```
 $reversedResult = array_reverse($result);
```

Using $reversedResult instead of $result in your while loop should work.

Comment: Problem is, i can't change the 10th result. And i get only 10 results which means i can't get id of a result in array of all of results.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. Can you confirm there are at least 10 records in the DB and there are no corrupt/bad records (e.g. with missing fields)?

Comment: Yes. I can confirm that.